# ngx-translate: use different directories for translation files

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate to translate buttons, headers, ... in my app and this works fine. My translation files are in the **/assets/i18n/** folder.

Now I have mockdata which I also have to translate, but my mockdata is in another directory -> **/assets/data/**

To load my json translations files from the **i18n** folder I use:

```
export function setTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

but now I also want to load the files from the **data** directory.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [ngx-translate-multi-http-loader](https://github.com/denniske/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader) which let you use multiple translation file.

[My stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-sm8hth?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Or

1. run `npm i ngx-translate-multi-http-loader`
2. in your `app.module.ts` file add

```js
import { MultiTranslateHttpLoader } from 'ngx-translate-multi-http-loader'

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    { prefix: 'assets/i18n/', suffix: '.json' },
    { prefix: 'assets/data/', suffix: '.json' },
  ])
}

// ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   TranslateModule.forRoot({
     loader: {
       provide: TranslateLoader,
       useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
       deps: [HttpClient],
     },
   }),
  ]
```

**EDIT**

If you get an `Something went wrong for the following translation file`, -> [here you have a way to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051268/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader-something-went-wrong-for-the-following-transla/69051269#69051269)