# ngx-translate-multi-http-loader : Something went wrong for the following translation file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate, ngx-translate-multi-http-loader

I was using this library [ngx-translate-multi-http-loader](https://github.com/denniske/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader) to being able to load multiple language file for my ionic 5 App.

I didn't had any errors, but the translation wasn't working.

Then I added inside the `TranslateModule.forRoot({})` the `defaultLanguage: 'en'`, and it then resulted in the following error message

> Something went wrong for the following translation file: ./assets/i18n/en.json
> Database not created. Must call create() first

I needed a lot of time to figure it out how to fix it and couldn't find no help on internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2023 Fix

This error shouldn't happen anymore with >= 9.2.0. Since the library is now using `httpBackend`

### The error

[This topic](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/641) pointed me in the right direction. Basically, the required loader that we use to import the translations files

```js
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, [
    { prefix: './assets/i18n/', suffix: '.json' },
    { prefix: `./assets/i18n/${APP_CONFIG.appType}/`, suffix: '.json' },
  ])
}
```

Is directly imported into the app.module.ts @ngModule

```js
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient],
  },
}),
```

If you find this post, it surely mean you're using an `HttpInterceptor` in your app, that does request the data from the ionic storage (or any other services) to apply a specific logic to the request -> Let say, you want to add a token to the request.

Let's have the following example

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _storage: Storage) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {

    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    let authReq: any
    return from(this.getToken()).pipe(
      switchMap((token) => {
        if (!req.headers.get('Authorization'))
          authReq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`),
          })
        else authReq = req.clone()

        //send the newly created request
        return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
          retry(1),
          catchError((err, caught) => {

            const error = (err && err.error && err.error.message) || err.statusText
            return throwError(error)
          }) as any,
        )
      }),
    )
  }

  getToken(): Observable<any> {
    const token$ = new Observable((observer) => {
      this._storage.get('token').then(async (token) => {
        if (token) {
          observer.next(token)
        } else {
          observer.next(ORGANISATION_TOKEN)
        }
      })
    })

    return token$
  }
}
```

Then, because the `ngx-translate-multi-http-loader` is requesting the translations file with the angular default `http` class, you'll be passing through this http interceptor. But the `_storage` isn't instantiated yet. which result in an `Database not created. Must call create() first` which make our request fail into the `Something went wrong for the following translation file: ./assets/i18n/en.json`

### The fix

We have to ignore this interceptor for that specific request.

For that purpose :

1. you could do it with a `httpBackend` -> [here an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49013534/11135174).
   But it wont work, because you wont have instantiate your services before the http call.
2. You have to add a specific header, that tell your `HttpInterceptor` to ignore the request and let it going through without further investigation. *Thx [JohnrSharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047764/11135174)*

```js
export const InterceptorSkipHeader = 'X-Skip-Interceptor'

@Injectable()
export class UsHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _storage: Storage, private _statusService: MegaphoneStatusService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    if (req.headers.has(InterceptorSkipHeader)) {
      const headers = req.headers.delete(InterceptorSkipHeader)
      return next.handle(req.clone({ headers }))
    }

   //... Intercept
```

For being able to pass that header into the `ngx-translate-multi-http-loader`, well.. you can't. because the library do not accept it, but it isn't complicated to copy it.

```js
// core.ngx-loader.ts

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core'
import merge from 'deepmerge'
import { forkJoin, Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { InterceptorSkipHeader } from '../http.interceptor'

export class MultiTranslateHttpLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private resources: {
      prefix: string
      suffix: string
    }[],
  ) {}

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(InterceptorSkipHeader, '') // <-- Our Skip interceptor

    const requests = this.resources.map((resource) => {
      const path = resource.prefix + lang + resource.suffix

      return this.http.get(path, { headers }).pipe( // <-- We add the header into the request
        catchError((res) => {
          console.error('Something went wrong for the following translation file:', path)
          console.error(res.message)
          return of({})
        }),
      )
    })

    return forkJoin(requests).pipe(map((response) => merge.all(response)))
  }
}
```

And there you are.